# how to continuously caputre all my network traffic?

Tags: linux, vpn, logging

I've got a Linux desktop that will be a gateway between my private network and the open internet. I'd like it to capture and store all network traffic passing through it continuously, 24/7 (until the HDD fills up ;). But it has to be more sophisticated, than just a one big packet dump:

1) I'd like to have some white-listing capability to selectively not store specific kinds of traffic (e.g. YouTube videos, BitTorrent downloads.) That probably means creating rules based on protocols, IPs/domains, header/content keywords, DPI maybe?

2) Store it in a way that makes it possible to easily query the captured data. Remember - this will get pretty big very soon with normal web usage. So my guess is, maybe some fast, flat database, like Redis?

I'm relatively new to Linux. I have a rudimentary knowledge of stuff like iptables and I found out about tcpdump/libpcap, but it seems too basic (see two points above.)

How do I go about this?

...

(This is a separate question, but I also welcome suggestions on how to query all this data. I need something high-level, like "get me all the files downloaded by that device/ip today", and not just a big Wireshark-style list of packets, which might be good for diagnostics, but not for efficient content retrieval and browsing.)

Comment: You might want to consider [NetworkMiner](http://sourceforge.net/projects/networkminer/) or, at the commercial end, [NetScout](http://www.netscout.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general networking rather than information security, and would be better suited to the [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) site or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Xander, thanks for the suggestion. Indeed, Security doesn't sound like the right place, but Network Engineering is still a small community and SuperUser doesn't sound like the right sort of crowd.

I'll try posting on Network Engineering, but moderators might kick my ass for double-posting. ;)

Comment: @xander, Sadly [Resource recommendations](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255/recommendations-and-polls) are off topic on NetworkEngineering.SE

Comment: This is so funny. So this question is off topic in Network Engineering, Security, and ServerFault? ;)

So where am I supposed to post it?

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/9/long-term-traffic-capture-wireshark/) talks about doing continuous capture with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) -- specifically, with the `dumpcap` utility which comes with Wireshark. The utility supports some filter expressions, based on port, IP address, protocol...

For more extensive filtering and searching abilities, some googling reveals the existence of [n2disk](http://www.ntop.org/products/n2disk/), which is not free (in neither sense of the term), but may be worth it (I have not tried it). Moreover, n2disk relies on [nDPI](http://www.ntop.org/products/ndpi/), which is free (GPL); it is a library, so you could potentially use it to write your own "capture record" application. Also have a look at [nProbe](http://www.ntop.org/products/nprobe/), which is also GPL (but with a fee -- this highlights the difference between the two notions of "free"), and which might fit your bill.

Comment: Wireshark probably won't be able to deal with such large amounts of data.

Dupmcap with libpcap seems interesting, but then it's too simple/basic.

The ntop family, on the other hand, is very interesting and I will certainly investigate. But, as you said, it's not exactly FLOSS.